# "Both of these" or "Both these"?

Tags: ellipsis, determiners

Are the two constructions above correct or one of them is incorrect? Which one then?

- **Both of these** images resemble an ocean.
- **Both these** images resemble an ocean.

Comment: There’s also: _Both images resemble an ocean_ (also correct and perhaps the best way to say it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, there are two images, you can say "Both of these images" or "Both these images" to refer to both the images. So, both of your sentences are grammatically correct.

You can also say,

> Both images resemble an ocean.

For more information, check : http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/both-and-both-of/

and http://www.grammarbank.com/both-both-of.html

Comment: Thank you. Oh. btw can we say Either these?

Comment: If you say 'Either or Either of these images, it could mean 'one or the other image. It doesn't matter which one. I'd advice you to read this link http://www.englishbaby.com/lessons/3941/member_submitted/both_both_of_neither_neither_of_either_either_of_!! Carefully.

Comment: @yubrajsharma: You can't say "either these images". That is definitely wrong. You can say "either image", in the singular.

Comment: Yes, I just realized the mistake, thanks for pointing it out.