# "are both" vs. "both are"

Tags: adverbs

In my another post (["time adverbs" vs. "adverbs of time"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239527/109190)) I said

> I suppose these 2 sentences are **both** grammatical and idiomatic.

I guess the sentence above is grammatical.

I also see lots of people use ["both these"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22both%20these%22) or ["both of these"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22both%20of%20these%22). And [both are grammatically correct](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/110670/109190).

So, I am thinking if it is still is grammatical when I rewrite that as

> I suppose **both of** these 2 sentences are grammatical and idiomatic.

Could someone please give a hint?

Comment: Note that, when including small numbers in text, we normally write them in words rather than numerals... two rather than 2.  You could actually omit **two** from the second sentence, since **both** may only be used with two things (sentences, in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sentence:

> I suppose these 2 sentences are both grammatical and idiomatic.

**both** refers to the two properties of the sentences, grammatical and idiomatic.

However, in the second sentence:

> I suppose both of these 2 sentences are grammatical and idiomatic.

**both** refers to the two sentences.